# Disable Intel HD Graphics Windows overscan, enlarge resolution to be out of display borders

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, resolution

I am looking for a way to set custom resolution on Windows PC to make it artificially hide parts of the screen. Display I am using is 55" TV connected via HDMI cable.

I tried using CRU and changing its parameters but without success, it is automatically scaling it down and adding black borders so all parts of the screen are visible.

Here is a photo of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an answer as asked, but have you considered a 3D-printed bezel with a smaller viewport which you can attach to the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you, like a plastic attachment over the TV?

Answer (score 0):

What you currently are trying is the effect [letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) vs. [pan and scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_and_scan). When the aspect ratio of the video signal does not fit to the aspect ration of the display.

Your test doing so resulted in "letterboxing". It is the task of the TV to decide how to display not fitting content.

=> You have to search the TV settings to switch to the the *pan and scan* behavior to crop the edges.

---

But seeing your image, I don't understand what you try to achieve:
You show a web browser with a content area, roughly fitting the TV 's aspect ratio.
To fill the screen with the content (not showing the pannels and program header), you could use the *full screen* mode <kbd>F11</kbd> of the web browser and use the browser's *zoom* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>  to make it perfectly fit.

*Perhaps you want to update your question to explain your desire more clear.*

### Update

> I want to artifactually enlarge my screen so start menu and task bar will be out of visible parts of the screen

As already written above, the way how to display the final video signal is the task of your display / TV. There are settings to manipulate this:

[image]
Unfortunately all TV manufacturers have their own on-screen-menu logic and available configuration entries.

But I'm not the friend by forcing a full screen presentation  this way. This way you loose the control over the not visible area. You also would have to be very accurate when sizing and placing the application window in the visible area.

=> This is not a professional way to achieve an application full screen experience.

---

##### Alternative: "Magnifier"

Also not professional but quick and dirty is the "Screen Magnifier" as part of Window's assistive tools. (Go to the settings and search "zoom" or "magnifier")

Not professional as this tool allows to digitally zoom the screencontent, making it larger than the screen (as desired by you), but by doing this the displayed information gets scaled so rendering the items blured.

---

##### Alternative: Full Screen Mode via <kbd>F11</kbd> key

Regarding your picture, the dispayd Chrome is sized to the windows size by using the caret symbol at the to-right of the application window.
*=> This is not the full screen mode.*

*To get the real full screen mode, you have to **hit the <kbd>F11</kbd> key**.*
Then the window framing and the windows desktop will disappear. Only the application content is visible.

This has to be supported by the app, but almost every web browser knows about the <kbd>F11</kbd> functionality, also standard applications like office apps and many more.

---

##### Alternative: Power BI internal presentation modes

If using the <kbd>F11</kbd> key does still not fully satisfy you, then it is because of the internal gimmicks of *Microsoft Online Office* and *Power BI*.

I don't have Power BI. But as Power BI is a tool for presenting data, I cannot imagine, that there aren't some useful focused full screen modes:

So having a look at the possibilities of the software might be useful. Perhaps you start here at Microsoft:

[Display content in more detail:  focus mode and full screen mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-focus)

There you also find the chapter *Work in full screen mode*:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I want to artifactually enlarge my screen so start menu and task bar will be out of visible parts of the screen and those corners of GUI in web browser will be on corners of the screen. I already tried with F11 and all types of full screen modes, but Microsoft Power Bi has natively design "full screen" to look like this, I just want to somehow bypass it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Using magnifier I can achieve what I am trying to, but will loss of quality, just for the note. Thanks

Comment: So the question is solved?